Why are Montgomery and twisted Edwards curve said to be all quadratic twist secure?
Simple question. According to SafeCurve, all twisted Edwards and Mongomery curves are quadratic twist secure. But why ?

twisted Edwards, not regular Edwards.

See https://safecurves.cr.yp.to/twist.html

@Lev but it doesn’t explains why
